# Python Selenium- Cant find correct element. Login Button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

#Thanks in advance for help. New to python, tried for hour trying to correct mistake.#

1. Trying to locate login button element. Attached is the image of the website  with the element of the login button. [please see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJfyG.png)
2. Below is code:

   ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    url = "https://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php/admin/index"
    username = 'xxxx'
    password = 'xxxxx'

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\kk\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\geckodriver.exe")

    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_name(name='aname').send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_name(name='apass').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//style[@type="submit"]')
   ```

Comment: do you get an error? have you tried with the full xpath?

Comment: I could copy xpath. then changed the code to :
     driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/ul/li/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input')

No error. The i just added ActionChains to input .click() after the xpath. However, getting an error

Comment: login = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/ul/li/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input')
login.click()


AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than finding it with a CSS selector. Why not use `find_element_by_xpath()`
To get the XPath of that element just right-click the HTML of the input in Inspect Element, hover over Copy and you'll see "Full XPath"

Comment: I could copy xpath. then changed the code to :
     driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/ul/li/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input')

No error. The i just added ActionChains to input .click() after the xpath. However, getting an error

Comment: login = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/ul/li/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input')
login.click()


AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: make elements element

Comment: so login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/ul/li/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input')

Comment: beautiful!  what a champion!!!! thanks mate. Worked perfectly

Comment: all is well. best of luck brother

Answer (score 0):

Issue is your xpath.
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//style[@type="submit"]')

Use below:

```
 driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')
```

or

```
 driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@value="login"]')
 #This is more accurate as many input tags could have type as submit
```

Also, please use some sort of wait as i am not sure if page will be loading  fast enough every time you launch URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the submit button by using any of these 2:

```
//input[@type="submit"]  or  //input[@value="login"]
```

They should work without any problem if you don't have any similar elements on your page (which I doubt)
But if you want to be more precise, you can mix these 2 into:

```
//input[@value="login" and @type="submit"]
```